# Calling sendJavascript() from PhoneGap service

Tags: cordova

I am using  [`Red-Folder Consultancy's`](http://red-folder.blogspot.in/2012/09/phonegap-android-background-service.html) background service for Phonegap. Basically I want to **call a Javascript function from Phonegap service java file**.

I read using `sendJavascript` , we can do it , but it is not working.

Can anyone please help me with how to invoke Javascript function from Java code?

```
public class MyService extends BackgroundService {
    private final static String TAG = MyService.class.getSimpleName();
    MainActivity mainActivity = new MainActivity();
    private String mHelloTo = "World";
    @SuppressLint("SimpleDateFormat")
    @Override
        protected JSONObject doWork() {
            JSONObject result = new JSONObject();
            try {
                Log.d(TAG, "Calling sendJavascript in java");
                mainActivity.sendJavascript("javascript:doSomethingWithData();");
                SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss");
                String now = df.format(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis()));
                String msg = "Hello " + this.mHelloTo + " - its currently " + now;
                result.put("Message", msg);
                Log.d(TAG, msg);
            } 
            catch (JSONException e) {
            }
            return result;
        }
}
```

Please find my code above for calling JavaScript function defined in `index.html`.

**it's not triggering.**

Comment: mainActivity is referencing the CordovaActivity (or DroidGap) object? if not, it will not work. Anyways, you will have to use Intetns, because they are the standard way to comunicate between activities and services.

Comment: @user2067818 If you could add some more code, specially the calling of this service, will be much helpful to us.